# Failed to execute goal. Could not download npm. Got error code 404 from server

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, aem

I'm trying to execute the following in my local AEM 6.5.12 instance...

```
mvn -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate -D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem -D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype -D archetypeVersion=35 -D appTitle="WKND Sites Project" -D appId="wknd" -D groupId="com.adobe.aem.guides" -D artifactId="aem-guides-wknd" -D package="com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd" -D version="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" -D aemVersion="6.5.12"
```

...but I keep getting errors, such as the following:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for WKND Sites Project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] WKND Sites Project ................................. SUCCESS [  0.457 s]
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - Core .......................... SUCCESS [ 18.337 s]
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - UI Frontend ................... FAILURE [  1.389 s]
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - Repository Structure Package .. SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - UI apps ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - UI content .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - UI config ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - All ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - Integration Tests ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - Dispatcher .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WKND Sites Project - UI Tests ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.499 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-22T11:20:18-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project aem-guides-wknd.ui.frontend: Could not download npm: Could not download https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-6.17.14.tgz: Unknown host No such host is known (registry.npmjs.org) -> [Help 1]
```

Here's my root pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v12.22.7</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.17.14</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Jar Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven Clean Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- BND Maven Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${bnd.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>bnd-process</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <bnd>
```

Initially, JAVA HOME was pointing to a JRE folder, but I've since changed it to point to a JDK. Also, there's another discussion where it was suggested to do the following, which worked for several people, but did not work for me:

Change the npm verson of pom.xml in ui folder from 6.4.1 to 3.10.8.

UPDATE: After updating the pom.xml file's npmVersion, I ran Maven again and now get this error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:npm (npm run prod) on project aem-guides-wknd.ui.frontend: Failed to run task: 'npm run prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Comment: Looks like a network/firewall/proxy problem: `Unknown host No such host is known (registry.npmjs.org)`

Comment: Are you running this in a corporate network? What happens if you try a different network?